# Multiple $and with multiple $or in $match mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**Expected condition**

```
if(pid==req.session.pid && 
   ((status==0 && StatusDate1>=somedate)||(status==1 && StatusDate2>=somedate)||
    (status==2 && StatusDate3>=somedate)||(status==0 && StatusDate1>=somedate)))
```

I have tried writing below `$match` statement to meet the above condition, but for some reason it is not as expected.

```
var match =  { $match: { 
    $and: [ 
        { practiceId: req.session.p_id },  
        {
            $or:[{status : 0, StatusDate1:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        }, 
        {           
            $or:[{status : 1, StatusDate2:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        },
        {           
            $or:[{status : 2, StatusDate3:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        },
        {           
            $or:[{status : 3, StatusDate4:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        }]
    }
}
```

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

**Update**

Tried below versions, still did not get what I was expecting.

**Attempt 1**

```
var match =  { $match: { 
    $and: [ 
        { practiceId: req.session.p_id }],
    $and:[  
        {
            $or:[{status : 0, StatusDate1:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        }, 
        {           
            $or:[{status : 1, StatusDate2:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        },
        {           
            $or:[{status : 2, StatusDate3:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        },
        {           
            $or:[{status : 3, StatusDate4:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        }]
    }
}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
var match =  { $match: { 
    practiceId: req.session.p_id ,
    $and:[  
        {
            $or:[{status : 0, StatusDate1:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        }, 
        {           
            $or:[{status : 1, StatusDate2:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        },
        {           
            $or:[{status : 2, StatusDate3:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        },
        {           
            $or:[{status : 3, StatusDate4:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        }]
    }
}
```

**Attempt 3**

```
var match =  { $match: { 
    practiceId: req.session.p_id,
        $and:[  
        {
            $or:[{status : 0,StatusDate1:{$gte:somedate}}], 
            $or:[{status : 1,StatusDate2:{$gte:somedate}}], 
            $or:[{status : 2,StatusDate3:{$gte:somedate}}], 
            $or:[{status : 3,StatusDate4:{$gte:somedate}}] 
        }
    ]
  }
```

}

Comment: Is "somedate" the same  in your `$or` expression?

Comment: @user3100115 Yes.. it is same...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Syntax :- { $or: [ expression1, expression2, ... ] }

See if this could help you:-

```
var match =  { $match: { 
$and: [ 
    { practiceId: req.session.p_id },  
    {
        $or:[{status : 0, StatusDate1:{$gte:somedate}},
             {status : 1, StatusDate2:{$gte:somedate}},
             {status : 2, StatusDate3:{$gte:somedate}},
             {status : 3, StatusDate4:{$gte:somedate}}] 
    }]
}
}
```

Added `,` separated condition inside `$or` . See [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/)

Comment: Glad to help you. :)